# How to identify which live wire go with which neutral wire?

Tags: electrical-panel

## Context

I have an old electrical panel, with fuses. I want to replace it with a new electrical panel with GFCI breaker.

[image: fuse panel] [image: Fuse]

In this panel there some problems, no color were respected, and the live wire and the neutral one are not together. Each fuse have a live wire, and all neutral are together.

[image: mass of wires]

On the new one, every GFCI breaker have his phase and his neutral, like on this photo:

[image: a breaker panel]

## Problem

I've identified all the live wire and all the neutral, but I don't know which live wire goes with which neutral wire.

I've seen a tool like this "cable pair finder meter", I think it could work, but I'm not sure, I've never used one.

[image: a cable toner]

**Is this a suitable tool for the job?**

---

**I think there is not only one answer to this problem, so I won't mark any as THE answer.**

Comment: In which part of the world is this? In most countries, all neutrals are just as neutral electrically, but legislation varies throughout the world.

Comment: In most panels, all the neutrals are connected together on one bus(piece of metal with screws you clamp neutrals to), so finding each neutral for each live wire not as important.  Would have a problem if neutrals are different colour than white(in North America, think blue in Europe).

Comment: It's in France, I think you are right all neutrals are the "same", but on the new panel the live wire are paired with a neutral

Comment: Every fuse is wired to something, for example a plug, one neutral and one live wire. And theses wires a passing throught the fuse. So i thaught it's better to pair the wires

Comment: A pain in the neck, but neutrals and lives usually make a circuit.  An ohm meter should read something else than open, if placed on hot/live and neutral, if light switch is on or something is plugged into an outlet.  All power is off doing this.

Comment: @crip659 I see, I think it could work where the circuit is not open, but if it's a wall plug, it will be open ? Is there another solution for theses ?

Comment: @GregoryBoutte Assuming France's regulations are remotely sensible, the fuse should *always* be on the live and *never* on the neutral. So swapping live and neutral is a problem, but trading neutrals between circuits doesn't matter. But regulations sometimes aren't sensible.

Comment: Plug a light or something in it.  Will help if it was on.  Could also cut a cord with a plug on it and connect the two wires, but this can be dangerous if someone turn on the power

Comment: @Hearth  It sounds like the new panels/breakers are RCDs/GFCI type with paired neutrals, not the older type.

Comment: plug a 9volt battery into the wall outlet on a given branch, then use a voltmeter to find the neutral that pairs with the hot. You could also use a 6v battery and 12v battery all at once as flags to reduce the number of trips made from room to panel.

Comment: @dandavis that's a great idea as long as there are no lights or devices plugged into outlet anywhere in the house.  If there is, the battery will probably die before you get to the panel. You should make this an answer.  It has the benefit that it can be done without installing the neutrals, without bypassing RCDs, and without power applied.

Comment: @crip659 Okay, if they're on a GFCI, then sure, you need to keep them paired. They only mentioned a fuse, though--and I would assume any circuits still using fuses are quite old. Anyway, if it does use a GFCI, that would give you a way to determine the pairs as well--cause a ground fault on one neutral and see which live gets cut off by the GFCI.

Comment: Yes I think it's GFCI breaker, I did not know that was the english term for this, I looked on google image and it look like the new panel. I've updated the post to mention the GFCI breaker.

Comment: How many fuses are there, i.e., how many "circuits" are there? You say no color was respected. Were different colors used for hots in different circuits? Different colors for neutrals in different circuits? Is the wiring done with individual wires pulled through a conduit? Does this wiring have a separate "ground" or "earth" in each circuit?

Comment: Are you or someone living in this dwelling while working on it? Will your work be inspected by an authority? How many lights and receptacles are there total in the structure? Is this a fully detached house?

Comment: In the current panel there is 7 fuses for 11 circuits. And for the colors, the previous owner used all kind of color for the live wire (even the ground color). The wires goes through a conduit inside the walls. Not every circuit have a ground.

Comment: Yes someone live in the dwelling, and it won't be inspected. There is like 15 lights in the house. By receptacles  you mean wall plug ? If it's the case there is around 20 wall plugs.

Comment: So you want to proceed with understanding to avoid improper connections that would cause a problem later that you would be responsible for. Are you the owner of this property? I think you should get an analysis by a licensed French electrician. Changing a fuse panel to a modern breaker panel requires understanding and probably experience, and you have the complication of non complying wiring due to color coding not respected (and who knows what else).

Comment: I don't know what equipment is available in France. Is it possible that you can remove each fuse from the "panel" and insert a breaker in each circuit? (AFIK we cannot do this in US). So if this is possible then basically all  you have to do is identify the neutral that goes to each hot and connect it to the neutral on each GFCI breaker. Ordinary breakers do not need to have  neutral identified and connect to the breaker. Is there a means of disconnecting power  to the fuse panel, i.e., a disconnect, outside or inside?

Comment: *In this panel there some problems* - namely that it doesn't exist. You can use that tracer so long as everything is de-energized and disconnected from absolutely everything. Basically you're in a situation where someone ran wires and then left before punching them down. Which means starting over from scratch while two steps behind, because you have to pull every outlet, switch, and fixture. - I do *this* for a living, but I don't have a pole long enough to touch *that*.

Comment: There is no point in installing GFCI if you don't have third, ground wire. That means rewiring everything from 2 to 3 wires, so your issue becomes moot. Also, you need separate neutrals for separate GFCls. If you have 1 GFCl like on the picture, then all neutrals go into it.

Comment: @Agent_L I respectfully disagree with the idea that "There is no point in installing GFCI if you don't have third, ground wire. " GFCI does not require a ground wire for proper operation. GFCI compares the current in Line and Neutral, and if they are sufficiently unequal, will trip the circuit, possibly saving your life.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135943/discussion-on-question-by-gregory-boutte-how-to-identify-which-live-wire-go-with).

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy GFCI requires some other path to create this unequality, and that's what ground wire is for. Without 3rd wire, the grounding pins in sockets are connected to neutral. GFCl is in this case useless - it will either never trip, if the environment is perfectly insulated or will be tripped all the time if there is even a slightest path between eg. computer case and a heater. That's what GFCI sockets are designed for.

Comment: @Agent_L GFCI is NOT useless without a ground wire. It could save your life. Think of someone using a hair dryer in a bathtub. When the dryer falls in the tub, GFCI trips, saving a life. In your example of a computer and heater, there may not be enough ground current between them to trip the GFCI until _you_touch both. Even in the case where GFCI trips all the time, it is telling you that if you power your circuit, you are in danger of electrical shock. It is telling you you need to fix something to be safe.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Hair dryer is en example of double-insulated device - it will work for that. But only that. A house when you can't use single-insulated device is useless. Correctly operating TN-C is not dangerous, but GFCI will still trip. I don't mean "useless" as in "it will never work" but as in "it will cause more bad than good". A GFCI socket, on the other hand, will provide 100% functionality.

Comment: @Agent_L I don't know where you are located, but in US, neutral is (or should be) connected to ground only _before_ the main breaker panel. The ground prong of a socket should never be directly connected to neutral. (You had written "Without 3rd wire, the grounding pins in sockets are connected to neutral."). I agree that _if_ you do that, a GFCI at the breaker panel, will be problematic. Surprised you call them GFCIs, however, because I was under the impression they went by a different name in countries that don't use the US system.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy You're describing current code, but OP's installation looks dated. And his locale says "France". I call them whatever they're called in the discussion. In my language it's neither GFCI nor RCD, same in French. So, to me both English terms are foreign translations, equally alien : ) I call them "differential-current breakers" and French term is similar. Not very understandable in English.

Comment: @Agent_L it isn't just current code. AFAIK, it has never been permissible to connect the neutral wire to the ground pin of a socket in the US.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I'm not arguing that. I'm arguing that there are jurisdictions and time periods when it was legal. US is clearly out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 5):

First, neutrals will generally be in the same conduit pipe as the partner live wire.

To identify the neutrals, plug a load into each circuit and turn the load on.  Lift all the neutrals off the neutral bar, and cap them off.

The presence of the load puts some conductivity (inverse of resistance) between the live and neutral wire on that circuit. Since the loop is not complete, there is not voltage drop through the load, and so full 230V will appear on neutral(s) connected to that live.

Energize one live wire at a time.  Check **every** neutral wire with a non-contact voltage detector (or contact detector if you wish).  You will see "floating" voltage (0V or low voltage reading) on the neutrals not connected, and live voltage (230V) on neutrals connected through a device to that live.  Generally, there should be exactly one neutral, and that is the partner.  Two neutrals indicates a wiring fault, which we hope we don't see - but it costs little to check for it.

If the house has multiple phases of power, seeing 2 or 3 lives sharing a neutral is not necessarily a wiring defect.

There's nothing wrong with fuses...  unless you are in the Philippines, where in the older areas both legs are hot. In that case you need a 2-pole breaker with overload protection on both sides.

*Note that those breakers are neutral-switching but are not 2-pole.  Look carefully at their diagram - they switch the neutral, but DO NOT have an "overload detector" on the neutral. Such breakers can only be used where neutral is at the same voltage as ground (or within 1 volt).*

Comment: @TooTea did not see that.  Thanks.

Comment: Would the device shown in the question be useful for determining which receptacles are on a given hot wire? Would determining that first help in being sure there was a load plugged into each circuit?

Comment: @JimStewart Sure, it's good for all manner of wire tracing, but IMO it's overkill.  A non-contact voltage tester will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm relying on your statement that you know which wires are neutrals, but not how they are paired with lives and I will assume the neutrals on the new panel go to a common bus, so you can install them all without identifying them first.

If you have an urgent need to identify *all* the neutrals I think the easiest way would be to use a clamp ammeter.  Find one with a thin flexible clamp probe that you can use on the neutrals when they're already on the bus.

1. Turn on lots of things all over the house
2. Clamp one neutral.  If it doesn't light up, keep turning things on til it does. Once it does ....
3. Turn off each breaker to find the corresponding one.
4. Rinse and repeat.  (Sorry that's an annoying American expression but you probably get it.).

While you're at it you can hopefully improve your breaker labeling.

If you do not have an urgent need to identify all of them you  can use this technique as and when you need it to find the neutral you need.

If my assumption is wrong, e.g. the neutrals have to be paired with RCDs, you could either *temporarily* put them all on a bus just to conduct this experiment or you could do this exercise in reverse: connect each neutral to a floating Wago, turn on one breaker at a time and use the Wago's test port to find which neutral has voltage to ground.

Answer (score 1):

## 1 - Finding the room behind every live wire

To find which neutral goes to which live wire, I first found where each live wire went.

To do so I just switch on every light. Then one by one I unpluged every fuse, then went on every room to see which light was off.

If no light were off, then it was a well plug that was on the fuse. So I took a lamp that I pluged on each wall plug, when the lamp stayed off I knew that it was the fuse that I unpluged.

## 2 - Pairing all neutral and live wire

Going from that I know where each live wire goes. The next step was to find the neutral to each live wire.

First I powered off the house.

I used two cable, one that was a computer power plug, but I joint the neutral and live wire of the cable, so that when I plug it, the circuit will be closed. And a second cable, a simple wire that I used to close the circuit of the light, after removing the light bulb.

Then I removed the live wire from the fuse, and for each live wire I closed the circuit corresponding to the wire using the cable described just before.

With an Ohm metter that make a sound when there a closed circuit, I touched the live wire with one cable of the ohm metter, and with the other one I touched every neutral, when I heard the bip of the Ohm metter I had the pair. I taped them together and went on the next live wire.

## 3 - Wiring all the breakers

Once I removed all the wire from the old planel, I removed the old panel and installed the new one on the wall.

Then all I had to do was to plug the pairs of wire into the breakers of the panel.

After that I powered on the house and checked every room to be sure that everythings works fine.